# Run code only on first open of program

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML file with a JavaScript `<script>` section in it. The first time a user opens the file, I need it to run a function, but not run it on any following openings of the file.

Comment: cookie or localstorage are options

Answer (score 1):

Like Jaromanda X is saying, use local storage.

```
if(localStorage){
    if(!localStorage.getItem("HasBeenOpened")){
        // run function here
    } else{
        localStorage.setItem("HasBeenOpened", true);
    }
}
```